# ffmpeg - Fill audio frame with audio sample

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, encoder

I'm trying to encode an audio stream to a file. I'm receiving the audio buffers and using `avcodec_fill_audio_frame` to create an `AVFrame` and send it to `avcodec_encode_audio2` (with some other thing in between - I`m using ffmpeg muxing.c as an example)

The thing is: The audio buffer I'm getting contains 480 samples, the codec I'm using has a `frame_size` of 1152 (MP2). The result is that the output audio file is kinda "chopped". It sounds like every audio frame has some silent samples in the end.

How can I fix this?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You must fill the `AVFrame` with up to `frame_size` (1152 in your case) samples before you pass the frame to `avcodec_encode_audio2`.

It sounds like your frame is too small. How are you setting it up? Can you show some code?

Comment: I'm receiving it from javascript WebRTC and using Google's Native Client to encode it.
In the C++ side, I use pp::MediaStreamAudioTrack ([link](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_dev/cpp/classpp_1_1_media_stream_audio_track)) to handle the stream. Then I can get the buffer and configure it.

These are the fields I can configure:
PP_MEDIASTREAMAUDIOTRACK_ATTRIB_BUFFERS,
PP_MEDIASTREAMAUDIOTRACK_ATTRIB_SAMPLE_RATE,
PP_MEDIASTREAMAUDIOTRACK_ATTRIB_SAMPLE_SIZE,
PP_MEDIASTREAMAUDIOTRACK_ATTRIB_CHANNELS,
PP_MEDIASTREAMAUDIOTRACK_ATTRIB_DURATION.

Do you need more information?

Comment: Should I create an intermediary buffer to fill it until it's 1152 and, only then, send it to the encoder?
If so, how can I create and fill this intermediary buffer?
Thanks :)